# wait while loop is over

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, promise

I have an arrow function which get two arrays as parameters then on certain condition i push items from second array to first array

The problem is that i have big amount of data that i should to push and `res.send` cant wait while loop is over and send me error about memory `JavaScript heap out of memory`

How i can wait while my loop is over and make loop to work faster? I just try with async/await, promiseAll, for await

```js
let mergeById = async(arr1, arr2) => {
  arr1.map(async(item) => {
    item.properties = [];
    await arr2.map(async(prop) => {
      if (item.item_id == prop.item_id) {
        await item.properties.push(prop);
      }
    })
  })
  return arr1
}

async someFunction(req, res) {

  arr1 = dataItems(); //6000 items
  arr2 = dataProps(); //60000 items

  let result = await mergeById(arr1, arr2);

  res.json({
    data: result
  })

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe try to rephrase your question? I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. All I can see from your code now is that nearly all your awaits do basically nothing

Comment: `await mergeById(arr1, arr2);` does not await for any of the inner `map(async(item) => {` and `arr2.map(async(prop) => {` ... `mergeById` immediately returns a promise taht resolves to `arr1` - BEFORE any of that internal code even starts let alone finishes

Comment: `await item.properties.push(prop);` ... why? Array.push is synchronous and returns the new length of the array, not a Promise, since an array.push is synchronous

Answer (score 2):

You have map inside map, therefore for each item in array1 it will iterate over whole array 2. You have encountered `O(n^2)` complexity and as you can see - even with 66 000 items (which is not that much for computer on its own), you are encountering huge impact. Because you have to do 6 000 * 60 000 = 360,000,000 iterations

There is a solution. You have to do some preprocessing - create `new Map()` for array2, iterate over all items and save `item_id` as a key with value `true`. Something like `array2Map.set(prop.item_id, prop)`

Then change your cycle to check your map

```
arr1.map(async(item) => {
    item.properties = [];
    const prop = array2Map.get(item.item_id);
    if (prop) {
        item.properties.push(prop)
    }
```

Now you have `O(n * log n)` complexity (well its almost `O(n)` because of pseudo-linear complexity of hashmaps, but thats different story, not that important now). And thats good enough for your use-case.

---

Also there is another problem with usage of the `await` and `async`. Just remove all this usage from all the code you have presented. It does not do anything useful, but actually breaks few things.

`.map` function runs synchronously no matter if you put `async` function as a parameter. It will just create an array of promises. Unless you know exactly what you are doing, my tip is that for array functions (map, foreEach, reduce etc.) never ever use async function as parameter - as it will mostly not work as you expect.

Comment: how will this solve the asynchrony issue that the OP as no clue about?